# UIPickerView Animation Hide and Show Failed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this on my interface file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
    <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDataSource>

// PickerView Array
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pickerNames;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pickerValues;    
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker;

- (IBAction)buttonSelectPicker;

@end
```

and I have this on my implementation file :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // PickerView Array
    _pickerNames = @[@"Data1", @"Data2", @"Data3", @"Data4", @"Data5"];
    _pickerValues = @[@"val1", @"val2", @"val3", @"val4", @"val5"];
    _picker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 1000, 320, 216);
}
```

all of those code works perfectly on my iPod (iOS 6.1.3) now, I have problems with what actually I want to do more... they are...

1. when the app loaded for the first time, UIPickerView is hidden (outside the screen area). I tried by adding this line (on `viewDidLoad`) but it didn't work.

   `_picker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 1000, 320, 216);`
2. then when user tap the `buttonSelectPicker` button, UIPickerView shows up. this lines of code also didn't work :

   `- (IBAction)buttonSelectPicker {
   [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
       [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
       _pickerviewContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 289, 320, 216);
       [UIView commitAnimations];
   }`
3. and when user tap anywhere outside UIPickerView area, it will hide the UIPickerView. I have this code to dismiss keyboard, but I don't know how to modify to dismiss UIPickerView :

   `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
       for (UIView * txt in self.view.subviews){
           if ([txt isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
               [txt resignFirstResponder];
           }
       }
   }`

thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can use:

```
  self.dataPicker.hidden=NO; and 
  self.dataPicker.hidden=YES;
```

at appropriate situation.

**Update**:
  Take UIPicker on some another view and then use

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
            self.infoView.frame = CGRectMake(0 , 70,  self.infoView.frame.size.width,  self.infoView.frame.size.height);

        }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         }];
```

where infoView is name of new UIView taken.
You need to call view animation method twice to hide(move it out of viewcontroller) and show view and change X,Y co-rdinates accordingly.

Comment: It works, bro. but can we put some animation delay on it? because it looks like popping up on the screen suddenly.

Comment: I try to apply your code like this and it only animate once : - (IBAction)buttonSelectMLM {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.33 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
        self.picker.frame = CGRectMake(0 , 70,  self.picker.frame.size.width,  self.picker.frame.size.height);
        self.picker.hidden = NO;
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
    
}

Comment: @RobertHanson: check last two lines of answer.

Answer (score 3):

You're basically recreating what `inputView` does. UIKit allows you to define any custom input method, not only the keyboard, thus, you can put an `UITextField`, and set the `inputView` as follows:

```
UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 162)];

picker.dataSource = self;
picker.delegate = self;

self.textField.inputView = picker;
```

(The picker could be as well be loaded from a nib)

Then you use the normal methods for text field handling

```
// Show keyboard/picker
[self.textField becomeFirstResponder]

// Dismiss keyboard/picker
[self.textField resignFirstResponder]
```

The picker will be presented instead of the keyboard when the text field becomes first responder. I don't know if this suits your needs, but consider it as an alternative, more cleaner way.